# How can I enlarge space between top node and bottom

Tags: graphviz

I want to make more space between node comm and other nodes. How can I do that? Here's the code:

```
digraph H {
    overlap="false"
    splines="polyline"
    nodesep=2;
    
 comm [
   shape=plaintext
  
   label=< 
     <table border='1' cellborder='1'>
       <tr><td colspan="3">Коммутатор</td><td port='34'>34</td><td port='36'>36</td><td port='38'>38</td><td port='37'>37</td><td port='40'>40</td><td port='39'>39</td><td port='47'>47</td><td port='48'>48</td><td port='49'>49</td><td port='51'>51</td></tr>
     </table>
  >]; 
con1 [
   shape=plaintext
   
   label=<
     <table border='1' cellborder='1'>
      
       <tr><td colspan="3">Континент 1 </td><td port='In1'>In1</td><td port='8'>8</td></tr>
     </table>
  >];
  con2 [
   shape=plaintext
   
   label=<
     <table border='1' cellborder='1'>
      
       <tr><td colspan="3">Континент 2 </td><td port='In1'>In1</td><td port='8'>8</td></tr>
     </table>
  >];

 comm:34 -> con1:in1;
 comm:36 -> con2:In1;
 comm:49 -> con1:8;
 comm:51 -> con2:8;
}
```

And it looks like that:[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aSYO.png)

I need to make more space because there will be much more nodes later and they'll placed in the horizontal line on same rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**ranksep**](http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/ranksep/) will alter the distance between ranks.

```
digraph H {
    overlap="false"
    splines="polyline"
    nodesep=2;
    ranksep=1.6  // spread the ranks
    
 comm [
   shape=plaintext
  
   label=< 
     <table border='1' cellborder='1'>
       <tr><td colspan="3">Коммутатор</td><td port='34'>34</td><td port='36'>36</td><td port='38'>38</td><td port='37'>37</td><td port='40'>40</td><td port='39'>39</td><td port='47'>47</td><td port='48'>48</td><td port='49'>49</td><td port='51'>51</td></tr>
     </table>
  >]; 
con1 [
   shape=plaintext
   
   label=<
     <table border='1' cellborder='1'>
      
       <tr><td colspan="3">Континент 1 </td><td port='In1'>In1</td><td port='8'>8</td></tr>
     </table>
  >];
  con2 [
   shape=plaintext
   
   label=<
     <table border='1' cellborder='1'>
      
       <tr><td colspan="3">Континент 2 </td><td port='In1'>In1</td><td port='8'>8</td></tr>
     </table>
  >];

 comm:34 -> con1:in1;
 comm:36 -> con2:In1;
 comm:49 -> con1:8;
 comm:51 -> con2:8;
}
```

Giving:
[image]